# Background image in HTML not showing up

Tags: html, css

I have this code in HTML:

```
.body { background: url('bg.png'); }
```

I have the HTML file in the same folder as the image, and the image has exactly the same name. I don't have a separate CSS folder, this code is inside  in my HTML file.

I have looked at other people with the same problem and none of the responses work.

Any response will be appreciated, even if it does not work. Thank you for your time!

Comment: have you tried .body { background: url('bg.png') no-repeat 0 0 /cover; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body tag is a tag, not a class. Remove your dot:

```
 body { background: url('bg.png'); }
```

Apply to this:

```
 <body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was a regular css rule line, like color or font-size, but I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`.body` refers to an element with a class `body`, to refer to the **body** tag just get rid of the dot...unless that was a typo.